# Не закрывается модальное окно (Popup) на iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, popup

Есть код:

```
  <script>
    $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            var container = $("#popup1");
            if (container.has(e.target).length === 0){
                container.hide();
            }
        });
  </script>
```

Он помогает закрыть модальное окно кликнув по не активной (фоновой) области не относящейся к модальному окну. Работает это только в Windows и Android, но не в iOS. Помогите исправить или предложите свой вариант.

p.s. исходник тут (зелёные кнопки):
https://yurii-hets.blogspot.com/#prices

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решён!

Нужно добавить в CSS код попапа для мобилки.
Как-то так:

```
@media (max-width: 1300px) {
.popup {
   cursor: pointer;
   }
}
```